# How to change gsp g:field size

Tags: grails, size, gsp

I tried setting 'size' property in the g:field tag and setting 'size' constraint in domain class but both failed.

Comment: Setting the `size` as a constraint does not affects the rendering of the view (except, maybe, for scaffolding). Setting the `size` in the `<g:field>` tag should work.

Comment: Sorry I don't recall any solution, this was 3 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

`size` should work on a `g:textField` since it just becomes an html input - make sure your css isn't limiting the size shown.